# Track page size of web app for performance

Tags: analytics, performance, measure, page-size

I'm about to start trialling optimisations on my web application (apache & tomcat). My main interest right now is:

- The total page size (including external js files such as jquery)
- The number of GETs per page

I'd like to setup a systematic way of measuring the consequences of the various changes I make over time.

Are there any tools that are useful for recording a sequence of page hits, playing this back (as I change the config) and record the size of each page ? Ideally I'd like something that can make work with a continuous integration server such as Continuum.

Rgds, Kevin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are useful, but they don't allow me to do the measurements I want to do in a repeatable, automated, systematic way.  After some more researching, this is a multi part problem. I will need to

- Use the Firebug plugin, and the YSlow plugin. YSlow will send a [beacon](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/beacons.html#yslow_beacon) to me containing stats
- Setup a server to receive, collect & report on these results
- Automate Firefox running against my web app from my continuous integration server.

Answer (score 1):

Instead or in additon to monitoring the page size I suggest to optimize for performance.

So monitor the page load time and idealy also your web app's transaction performance. If you google for "real browser monitoring" you will see a some providers like [AlertFox](http://www.alertfox.com/).

Another totally free option is to run  the performance monitoring *locally* with iMacros, Google Page speed,Selenium...

[Google page spee](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)d also gives you page size and # of gets ;-)

Comment: I've got a separate process to do load tests on the application itself. The web app is designed for mobile phones, so while the speed of data transfer is variable, the number of bytes downloaded and nbr of concurrent GETs is a good indicator of expected performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

**In Chrome:**

- [Google Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/), directly in the browser (no need to install).

  - `[menu]` ⇒ `Tools` ⇒ `Developer Tools` (what you are looking for is in the [Resources Panel](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/resources.html))
- [Google Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl?hl=en), but be careful with it: you need to use an unstable version of Chrome, and I've stopped to use it because of that.

**In Firefox**

- [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/1843/)

  - Take a look to the [Net Panel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel)
- [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)
- [Yahoo! YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)